# Object not found when creating an R function

Tags: r, function, replace, dplyr

dataframe I am trying to create a function based on a bit of code that works so I can replicate it further.

```
nap_analyse <- nap_analyse %>%
  mutate(is.beekper = as.logical(replace(About_yourself.Beekeeper, !is.na(About_yourself.Beekeeper), TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(is.beekper = replace_na(is.beekper, FALSE))
```

The above code seems to work well and therefore I am trying to create the function below:

```
new_nap_var <- function(dataframe, new_var, var_to_replace) {
  dataframe <- dataframe %>%
    mutate(new_var = as.logical(replace(var_to_replace, !is.na(var_to_replace), TRUE))) %>%
    mutate(new_var = replace_na(new_var, FALSE))
}
```

However, when I run  `new_nap_var(nap_analyse, is.beekeeper, About_yourself.Beekeeper)` I get the error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `new_var`.
> x object 'About_yourself.Beekeeper' not found
> ℹ Input `new_var` is `as.logical(replace(var_to_replace, !is.na(var_to_replace), TRUE))`.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

How can I make this work? Many thanks!

Comment: Use `{{..}}` around the variable names in the function. (eg - `{{var_to_replace}}`)

Comment: Thanks Ronak, however, I get the same error as above.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this function :

```
new_nap_var <- function(dataframe, new_var, var_to_replace) {
  dataframe %>%
    mutate({{new_var}} := as.logical(replace({{var_to_replace}}, 
                                     !is.na({{var_to_replace}}), TRUE))) %>%
    mutate({{new_var}} := replace_na({{new_var}}, FALSE))
}

new_nap_var(nap_analyse, is.beekeeper, About_yourself.Beekeeper)
```

Comment: would one not need `(...) dataframe <- dataframe %>% (...)`? I tried what you suggested and the function runs without errors, but when I run `nap_analyse$is.beekeeper` I get `> nap_analyse$is.beekeeper
NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `is.beekeeper`. `

Comment: don't assign inside the function. Do `nap_analyse  <- new_nap_var(nap_analyse, is.beekeeper, About_yourself.Beekeeper)`